# Wordpress Issue that is baffling me?

Tags: wordpress

I just transferred a WordPress site over to a new hosting account and i am having a strange problem the WordPress url is blog.net/blog how ever when i click on links i get page not found when i look up at the url its blog.net/pagename. it seems to be ignoring the sub directory. i have tried updating the permalinks.
Please help?
here is  the link [www.anastasioumedia.com/guest](http://www.anastasioumedia.com/guest)
when i click on images on the homepage it shows up as [www.anastasioumedia.com/](http://www.anastasioumedia.com/guest).

Comment: You need to go to: `Settings > Permalinks` in the dashboard select the same structure as in the previous site and save and the URL should be working.

Answer (score 1):

**`.htaccess` To Redirect URLs**

Just copy and paste the snippet below into site `.htaccess` and replace `example.com` with your domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: i deleted the htaccess file and also tried the permelink and that did not work